# Why the expression 'T foo = T()' is not copy initialized

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constructor, initialization, copy-constructor

I have the following class definition:

```
class T
{
    string text;

public:
    T() : text{} 
    {
        // ...
    }

    T(T &other)
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

And the following initialization:

```
T cp_f = T();
```

From what I can understand about object initialization this is a `value (default)` initialization (`T()`) followed by a `copy` initialization (`T cp_f = ...`). But when I execute this code the copy constructor is never called. At first I assumed that the compiler is optimizing the redundant temporary but even with optimization turned off the behavior persists.

Why this expression does not result in a copy initialization?

PS: I'm using the VC++ compiler version 19.10.25017 for x86/

Comment: @MarkRansom This is invalid C++14 because of the missing `const` on the copy constructor (which still has to exist and be callable even though the call is elided), and valid C++17. MSVC doesn't claim to implement the  C++17 rules, so I think this is their extension allowing non-const lvalue refs to bind to rvalues at work again.

Comment: @T.C. good point, I missed that detail. But I still think the duplicate question provides an answer.